# Vue-Router: Detected an infinite redirection in a navigation guard when going from "/" to "/login"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, redirect, vue-router

I want to block pages if there is no authentication token and redirect to login page.
I've got two .ts pages (main and routes)

routes:

```
import { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';
const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: '/login/',
    name: 'Login',
    component: () => import('layouts/LoginLayout.vue')
  },

  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/DVRLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: () => import('pages/DashboardPage.vue') },
      { path: 'settings', component: () => import('pages/AppSettings.vue')},
    ],
  },

  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
    component: () => import('pages/ErrorNotFound.vue'),
  },
];
export default routes;
```

main

```
import {
  createMemoryHistory,
  createRouter,
  createWebHashHistory,
  createWebHistory,
} from 'vue-router';

import routes from './routes';


export default route(function () {

  const Router = createRouter({ routes });
  
  Router.beforeResolve(async(to, from, next) => {
    if(!document.cookie){
      next('/login')
    } else {
      next('/')
    }

  })
  return Router;
});
```

On load page address is localhost/#/, then it immediately try to redirect to /login and error appears:

*[Warning] [Vue Router warn]: Detected an infinite redirection in a navigation guard when going from "/" to "/login". Aborting to avoid a Stack Overflow. This will break in production if not fixed. (vue-router.js, line 43)

Unexpected error when starting the router:
Error: Infinite redirect in navigation guard
(anonymous function) — vue-router.mjs:3178*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Router.beforeResolve` runs before every navigation, even navigations initiated by the guard itself. The first redirect to `/login` starts a new navigation so the guard activates again and `!document.cookie` is still true so it redirects again to `/login` and this repeats forever.

The `else { next('/') }` is also probably not what you want.  It means no matter where the user tries to navigate, as long as `!document.cookie` is false, always direct them to "`/`".  I think you just mean to call `next()` which means "continue with the current navigation, wherever that may be"

Try

```js
Router.beforeResolve(async (to, from, next) => {
  if (!document.cookie && to.path !== '/login') {
    next('/login');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```